# Record fields in z3

Tags: z3

model record by datatype in z3

if two record datatype have the same field, e.g.,

```
 UNI_MSG : record
    Cmd : UNI_CMD;
    Proc : NODE;
    HomeProc : boolean;
    Data : DATA;
  end;

  INV_CMD : enum {INV_None, INV_Inv, INV_InvAck};

  INV_MSG : record
    Cmd : INV_CMD;
  end;

  RP_CMD : enum {RP_None, RP_Replace};

  RP_MSG : record
    Cmd : RP_CMD;
  end;
```

*both UNI_MSG  and RP_MSG have the fields Cmd.
when I use the Cmd field of a UNI_MSG record variable, I don't know how to 
use it because an RP_CMD variable also has the Cmd field.
z3 code is as follows:*

```
; This example illustrates basic arithmetic and 
; uninterpreted functions
(declare-datatypes () ((CACHE_STATE CACHE_I CACHE_S CACHE_E)))
(declare-datatypes () ((NODE_CMD NODE_None NODE_Get NODE_GetX)))
(declare-datatypes () ((UNI_CMD UNI_None UNI_Get UNI_GetX UNI_Put UNI_PutX UNI_Nak)))
(declare-datatypes () ((INV_CMD INV_None INV_Inv INV_InvAck)))
(declare-datatypes () ((RP_CMD RP_None RP_Replace)))
(declare-datatypes () ((WB_CMD WB_None WB_Wb)))
(declare-datatypes () ((SHWB_CMD SHWB_None SHWB_ShWb SHWB_FAck)))
(declare-datatypes () ((NAKC_CMD NAKC_None NAKC_Nakc)))
(define-sort NODE () Int)
(define-sort DATA () Int)
(define-sort boolean () Bool)
(declare-datatypes () ((Record_0 (mk-Record_0 (Cmd NAKC_CMD)))))
(declare-datatypes () ((Record_1 (mk-Record_1 (Data DATA)
(HomeProc boolean)
(Proc NODE)
(Cmd SHWB_CMD)))))

(declare-datatypes () ((Record_2 (mk-Record_2 (HomeInvSet boolean)
(InvSet (Array  NODE  boolean))
(HomeShrSet boolean)
(ShrSet (Array  NODE  boolean))
(ShrVld boolean)
(HomeHeadPtr boolean)
(HeadPtr NODE)
(HeadVld boolean)
(Dirty boolean)
(Local boolean)
(Pending boolean)))))

(declare-datatypes () ((Record_3 (mk-Record_3 (CacheData DATA)
(CacheState CACHE_STATE)
(InvMarked boolean)
(ProcCmd NODE_CMD)))))


(declare-datatypes () ((Record_4 (mk-Record_4 (CurrData DATA)
( NakcMsg (  Record_0))
( ShWbMsg (  Record_1))
( WbMsg (  Record_1))
( HomeRpMsg (  Record_0))
( RpMsg (Array  NODE  Record_0))
( HomeInvMsg (  Record_0))
( InvMsg (Array  NODE  Record_0))
( HomeUniMsg (  Record_1))
( UniMsg (Array  NODE  Record_1))
(MemData DATA)
( Dir (  Record_2))
( HomeProc (  Record_3))
( Proc (Array  NODE  Record_3))))))


(declare-const Sta  ( Record_4)) 

(assert (= (Cmd (select (UniMsg Sta)  1 )) UNI_Nak))

(check-sat)
```

The error is caused by both record_0 and record_1 having field Cmd.

Answer (score 0):

You can work around this by renaming them to `Cmd0`, `Cmd1` etc.

SMTLib actually allows the same name to be used in fields with other types, but the type system is too weak and requires you to put ascriptions to work around it. If you really want to keep the name, post a (much!) smaller version of this problem so we can show you how to do that. But in practice, renaming is the best (and simplest!) way to go.